# How should I write to get '2' as output in this class?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ParentClass
{
public:
    int id;

    ParentClass(int id)
    {
      this->id = id;
    }

    void print()
    {
      cout << id << endl;
    }
  };

class ChildClass: public ParentClass
{
public:
    int id;

    ChildClass(int id): ParentClass(1)
    {
      this->id = id;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ChildClass c(2);
    c.print();

    return 0;
}
```

I run this C++ file and I get '1' as output, I want to know how should I write to get '2' as output ? Or say that how to access a redefined variable from a derived class.

Comment: Remove `int id;` in `ChildClass`.

Comment: In addition to what @BoBTFish says, when calling the base constructor then do `ParentClass(id)` instead. Then remove the assignment inside the `ChildClass` constructor.

Comment: @BoBTFish What if I want to have a redefined variable in ChildClass ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  What if I want to have a redefined variable in ChildClass ?

Comment: In this case you are calling the parent version of print because print function doesn't exists in your child class, write a print function in your child class and then you will be able to see child version of the variable

Comment: Then I would ask *why*? If you redefine the same variable in the child-class you will have two *different* variables with the same name and in different scopes. The parent class have no way of knowing about the variables in the child class. The only solution then is to override `print` in the child class, which is kind of stupid and will probably lead to problems down the road.

Comment: Please give your questions a meaningful title.

Comment: Thank you guys. I know what my problem is and I will rethink for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access `ChildClass::id` from `ParentClass::print`. More generally: You cannot access members of a derived class, from a member function of the parent.

You can access `ChildClass::id` within the member functions of `ChildClass`.

`ChildClass::id` isn't a "redefined" variable. It is a separate, unrelated variable that happens to have the same identifier, but in different scope. There is no concept of "redefining" a member variable in a derived class, in C++.

---

I recommend considering, whether it makes sense for `ChildClass` to have two different ids.

Comment: Thank you. I would consider what I really want.

Answer (score 0):

Your ChildClass is doing some wrong or discutable stuff:
 1. it's "shadowing" the int id member of ParentClass
 2. it's calling the ParentClass constructor passing 1 (instead of "id")
 3. it's using assignements in constructors instead of initializer lists
 4. ParentClass::id visibility may be decreased from public to protected or private.

Try the following modified code:

```
#include <iostream>

class ParentClass
{
public:
    int id;

    ParentClass(int id) : id(id) {}

    void print()
    {
      std::cout << id << std::endl;
    }
  };

class ChildClass: public ParentClass
{
public:
    ChildClass(int id): ParentClass(id) {}
};

int main()
{
    ChildClass c(2);
    c.print();

    return 0;
}
```